# Delphi: How can I add a new category in ActionManager?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, tactionmanager

I'd like my actions to be organized in categories, but in the "Categories" box, I can't add a new category.

When I click add standard action, it has different categories like "Edit", "Internet",... . Is it even possible to have custom categories or I am stuck with default categories?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add a 'New Action' from the ActionManager's customize dialog, select the new action in the dialog, then in the 'Object Inspector' change its `Category` from '(No Category)' to something else.

Comment: You just start typing to make the change - type anything you want

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was straight forward. I am feeling like a true newbie right now!!

Comment: @Flom - A d'oh moment? <g> Yeah, I know the feeling quite well.. ;)